# Making a "panel" in WINapi

Tags: c++, winapi

I need to make a Panel (borderless Window?) with WinAPI for wxWidgets since I need one with CS_OWNDC to always have the same DC.

What styles should I use?

I do not program winapi very often, so I beg you to help me out :-).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[CreateWindow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632679%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) / [CreateWindowEx()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with [WS_CHILD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632600%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) would create a borderless/menubarless window (aka panel).

You'll have to register a custom window class (`RegisterClass()`) for your custom window panel if you want an alternate class style than one that is already provided by the common controls ("static" for instance).

Are you sure you want to use the `CS_OWNDC` class style?  See the [class styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff729176%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to make sure you're not thinking of `CS_CLASSDC`.

Comment: Yep, I am sure about it. Thanks for your answer.Need it for OpenGL.

Comment: Sure thing.   Good luck with your project!